# How to test if an object is an array of arrays/jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, types, jagged-arrays

I'm trying to test what kind of array an object is: 1D, 2D, or an array of arrays/jagged array.

Here's what I tried:

```
    if (o is Array && ((Array)o).Rank == 2) {
        Console.Write ("2D-Array:  ");
    } 
    /* else if (o[0] is Array) {
        Console.WriteLine ("Jagged Array:  ");
    } */
    else if (o is Array) {
        Console.Write ("1D-Array:  ");
    }
```

But the middle test doesn't work because `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'`

How else could you do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use [GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.array.getvalue.aspx). But does this `new object[]{new object[0],3}` a jagged array?

Answer (score 3):

Since `o` is an `object` and you did not box it as an array, this code won't compile. Here's an easier way:

```
var arr = o as Array;
if(arr != null) 
{
    if(arr.Rank == 2) 
    {
        Console.Write ("2D-Array:  ");
    } 
    else if (arr.Length > 0 && arr.GetValue(0) is Array) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Jagged Array:  ");
    } 
    else
    {
        Console.Write ("1D-Array:  ");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can not index `Array` either.

Comment: @PetSerAl Correct, I saw `Array` implements `IList` but I didn't make sure the implementation wasn't explicit. Fixed.